# Merging multiple results to one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT location.dep_id, location.county, names.name, coords.lat_dec, coords.lon_dec, commodity.commod
FROM location, names , coords, commodity
WHERE location.dep_id=names.dep_id AND names.line=1 AND location.dep_id=coords.dep_id AND location.dep_id=commodity.dep_id AND commodity.import='primary' AND location.state_prov='nevada'
```

The problem is that the commodity.import column can have multiple matches for "primary". For the query output, what I need is for multiple values of "primary" to be placed in one cell so that results "gold", "silver", and "unobtanium" would be listed in one cell in the commod column "gold silver unobtanium" rather than having 3 rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to learn proper join syntax.  It is more powerful (because it provides support for `left` and `right` outer joins, for instance); it makes the queries easier to understand; and it prevent errors caused by missing join conditions.

The answer to your question is to aggregate the data and then group the values together:

```
SELECT location.dep_id, location.county, names.name, coords.lat_dec,
       coords.lon_dec,
       group_concat(commodity.commod separator ' ') as commods
FROM location join
     names
     on location.dep_id=names.dep_id  join
     coords
     on location.dep_id=coords.dep_id join
     commodity
     on location.dep_id=commodity.dep_id
WHERE AND names.line=1 AND commodity.import='primary' AND location.state_prov='nevada'
group by location.dep_id;
```

I think that's right.  The first argument to `group_concat()` should be the column in `commodity` that you want to combine together.

If there are duplicates, you can remove them using:

```
       group_concat(distinct commodity.commod separator ' ') as commod
```

Comment: thanks that is getting me close. I believe that you meant to use commodity.import rather than commodity.primary in the group_concat function. I did that and I get the records formatted properly but the values for the commod column are incorrect. "Gold Silver Lead" instead reads "primary primary primary"

Comment: I think you want `commodity.commod` for the group concat.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using group_concat? (ref: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/)

Comment: I tried that per your suggestion (thanks) but it seems there's a bit more that needs to be changed in my query to get this working.

Comment: I'd refer to Gordon's definitive answer but the core idea was using aggregate function to merge your records.